# SPFX Extension Field Customizer onRenderCell calling base method

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

Currently i'm implementing field customizer to update document library list item icon. I updated Field XML Schema definition through CSOM. It's working well.

But for certain condition, I need to show the original icon.

```
@override
public onRenderCell(event: IFieldCustomizerCellEventParameters): void {
    var a = "1";
    if(a == 1){
      // change innerHTML
    }
    else{
      super.onRenderCell(event);
      // its not working
    }
}
```

is it possible to refer to the base method ? how can we do that ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: its DocIcon built in field

Comment: can you be more clear ? are you modifying the DocIcon inner html based on certain condition ? what type of condition ?

Comment: hi, on my case, i would like to change the DocIcon inner html if the document is checkout by specific user. Otherwise need to show the original icon as it is

Comment: This issue on SP git: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3759. It is not possible now, you have to do it manually.

Please vote up for implementing this feature on https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/31530607-field-customizer-ability-to-call-ootb-render-meth